# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

Tags: java, android

I copied my project  from Infoscrapper project to Infoscrapper2. After that I continiously recieve runtime exception. `com.example.infoscrapper.CropImageView"` cannot be found. however , package com.example.infoscrapper does not exist any more, there is no imports to it and there is not explicit activity call.
Activity is called

```
public void crop(View v) {
    if (imPhoto.getDrawable() != null) {
        Intent addAdv = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                CropImageActivity.class);

        startActivity(addAdv);
    }
}
```

What can cause such behaviour?

log

```
   04-18 02:17:33.273: E/AndroidRuntime(18942): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.infoscrapper2/com.example.infoscrapper2.CropImageActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class com.example.infoscrapper.CropImageView
    04-18 02:17:33.273: E/AndroidRuntime(18942):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
    04-18 02:17:33.273: E/AndroidRuntime(18942):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
    04-18 02:17:33.273: E/AndroidRuntime(18942):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
    04-18 02:17:33.273: E/AndroidRuntime(18942):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
    04-18 02:17:33.273: E/AndroidRuntime(18942):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    04-18 02:17:33.273: E/AndroidRuntime(18942):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
    04-18 02:17:33.273: E/AndroidRuntime(18942):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
    04-18 02:17:33.273: E/AndroidRuntime(18942):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-18 02:17:33.273: E/AndroidRuntime(18942):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    04-18 02:17:33.273: E/AndroidRuntime(18942):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1069)
    04-18 02:17:33.273: E/AndroidRuntime(18942):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:885)
    04-18 02:17:33.273: E/AndroidRuntime(18942):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    04-18 02:17:33.273: E/AndroidRuntime(18942): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class com.example.infoscrapper.CropImageView
    04-18 02:17:33.273: E/AndroidRuntime(18942):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
    04-18 02:17:33.273: E/AndroidRuntime(18942):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    04-18 02:17:33.273: E/AndroidRuntime(18942):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    04-18 02:17:33.273: E/AndroidRuntime(18942):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    04-18 02:17:33.273: E/AndroidRuntime(18942):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    04-18 02:17:33.273: E/AndroidRuntime(18942):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    04-18 02:17:33.273: E/AndroidRuntime(18942):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:375)
    04-18 02:17:33.273: E/AndroidRuntime(18942):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1997)
    04-18 02:17:33.273: E/AndroidRuntime(18942):    at com.example.infoscrapper2.CropImageActivity.onCreate(CropImageActivity.java:27)
    04-18 02:17:33.273: E/AndroidRuntime(18942):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
    04-18 02:17:33.273: E/AndroidRuntime(18942):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
    04-18 02:17:33.273: E/AndroidRuntime(18942):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2552)
    04-18 02:17:33.273: E/AndroidRuntime(18942):    ... 11 more
    04-18 02:17:33.273: E/AndroidRuntime(18942): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.infoscrapper.CropImageView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.infoscrapper2-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.infoscrapper2-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    04-18 02:17:33.273: E/AndroidRuntime(18942):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    04-18 02:17:33.273: E/AndroidRuntime(18942):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
    04-18 02:17:33.273: E/AndroidRuntime(18942):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
    04-18 02:17:33.273: E/AndroidRuntime(18942):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
    04-18 02:17:33.273: E/AndroidRuntime(18942):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
```

my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.infoscrapper2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TutorialActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AudioRecordTest"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".FingerPaintActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".GraphicsActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CropImageActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: did you try to clean the project and run again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This suggests that one of your XML resource files still refers to the old name:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class com.example.infoscrapper.CropImageView
```

Comment: i specificly posted my manifest to demonstrate that thare is no com.example.infoscrapper.CropImageView

Comment: My answer did not suggest a problem with your manifest. My answer is suggesting that there is an XML resource file in <project-dir>/res that refers to the old classname. For example, maybe <project-dir>/res/layout/foo.xml still refers to the old classname.

Comment: Yes, its right. Problem was cause old by old reference to custom view in layout

Answer (score 0):

It clearly says that "ClassNotFoundException". Check your apk file whether CropImageView class is there. Second do a clean build and create a apk file once again.

Comment: You probably did not read xplanation or they are confusing. com.example.infoscrapper2.CropImageView is there. com.example.infoscrapper.CropImageView is not there and should NOT be. and there is nor reference to com.example.infoscrapper.CropImageView. In my intire project there is no line com.example.infoscrapper.CropImageView at all and should not be. But somehow it is still called instead of com.example.infoscrapper2.CropImageView

Answer (score 0):

Try to rebuild the project.  Or clean, then build.